# Auto tab within sap.ui.table.Table in UI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Good day,

I want to impliment either jQuery.autotab, like this question in SCN
[Auto tabbing in SAP UI5](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3733755).

I am very new to javascript and would like some assistance with this.

My table looks like this

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.MultiToggle
 });

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
     label : 'Work Request',
     template : new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
         value : '{requestNo}',
         editable : true
     })
}));

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label : 'Description',
    template : new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
        value : '{description}',
        editable : true
    })
}));
```

the answer in SCN suggested to look at jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $('.number').autotab('filter','number');

});

$('.number') here .number is the classname.
```

My question is, how do i get this to work?  The example is using normal text fields, but I need to autotab like in Excel between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add the respective `styleClass` to your `table`.

```
oTable.addStyleClass('number');
```

then in **onAfterRendering()** have your jQuery statements.

```
$(function () {
    $('.number').autotab('filter','number');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil. i think we are almost there.  I added the code exactly like that but i get the following error now: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autotab is not a function. Can you please help me out?